# C++11 Allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, allocator

I have not seen many good examples or tutorials on how to create a custom allocator in C++11. I do see that it has changed since C++03. However, I didn't know how to do it then either.

I've got the following that I threw together via as much information as I could find:

```
// Project Includes
#include "IMemoryManager.h"

// Standard Includes
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <summary>
/// A STL compliant custom allocator
///
/// Based on Dr Dobbs article
/// http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-what-are-allocato/184403759
/// I attempted to make it C++11 compliant.
/// Takes an Interface to a Memory Manager which will implement the custom memory management solution.
/// </summary>
template <class T>
class CustomAllocator
{
    std::unique_ptr<IMemoryManager> m_memoryManager;

public:

    typedef T value_type;

    /// Allocator takes ownership of memory manager
    CustomAllocator(std::unique_ptr<IMemoryManager> memoryManager)
        :
        m_memoryManager(std::move(memoryManager))
    {
    }

    ~CustomAllocator()
    {
    }

    CustomAllocator(const CustomAllocator & rhs) = delete;
    void operator =(const CustomAllocator & rhs) = delete;

    bool operator == (const CustomAllocator<T> & rhs)
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool operator != (const CustomAllocator<T> & rhs)
    {
        return false;
    }

    template <class U>
    CustomAllocator(const CustomAllocator<U> & rhs)
        :
        m_memoryManager(std::move(rhs.m_memoryManager))
    {
    }

    T * allocate(size_t n)
    {
        const size_t numBytes = n * sizeof(T);
        void * p = m_memoryManager->allocate(numBytes);

        if (!p)
        {
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }

        std::cout << "Allocated " << numBytes << " bytes for a " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
        return static_cast<T *>(p);
    }

    void deallocate(T * p, size_t numObjects)
    {
        const size_t numBytes = sizeof(*p);

        m_memoryManager->free(p);
        std::cout << "Deallocated " << numBytes << " bytes for a " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }

    void construct(T * p, const T & x)
    {
        // 'Placement new' constructs an object at a specified location
        // The custom allocator seperates allocation from construction
        new(p) T(x);
    }

    void destroy(T * p)
    {
        p->~T();
    }
};
```

I've got several questions about it.

1. How do I do the operator == and operator != not that it has a member variable that is a unique pointer? Do I just compare the address of the memory manager? Why does the standard ask me to implement comparison operators anyway if there is only supposed to be one of these and it is not copyable? Or does it?
2. Is it safe to move the memory manager in the copy constructor for the type U? I assume when the STL containers make a new allocator for a different type, it no longer uses the old. Is that correct?
3. I did not see construct or destroy methods anymore at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator#Allocator_completeness_requirements Do I still need to implement those?
4. How do I pass the argument to the Allocator's constuctor when I use it as an argument for an STL container?

```
void RunCustomAllocator()
{
    // Does not compile
    std::vector<ComplexNumber, CustomAllocator<ComplexNumber> > myVector;
    ComplexNumber number(1, 1);
    myVector.push_back(number);
}
```

Am I barking up the right tree here? Is this how we do custom memory management these days?

Comment: Here's a [guide](https://rawgit.com/google/cxx-std-draft/allocator-paper/allocator_user_guide.html) you could try.

Comment: 1) `operator==` should return true iff memory allocated by one allocator can be successfully freed by the other. You decide under what circumstances this condition holds for your class. E.g. `std::allocator` is stateless, and so any two instances of it compare equal.

Comment: 2) *"Is it safe to move the memory manager in the copy constructor"* Generally not - that's what move constructor is for. A copy constructor usually takes a reference to const, and you can't move away from a const object. That's not specific to allocators, it applies to any class in most cases.

Comment: @Kerrek I duplicated what the guide did in its first example, using the ArenaAllocator, and Visual Stuidio 2015 is hitting a breakpoint somehwere internally and giving me a message "Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00000262127F0000, 00000262128037D0 )" immediatly after my vector is constructed.

Comment: 3) `construct` and `destroy` are in fact listed in the article you cite (so I'm confused by your "didn't see" claim), though they are marked optional. If you don't provide them, then the object will be constructed in the allocated memory via placement new, and destroyed via explicit destructor invocation (which is suitable most of the time).

Comment: @igor The article is supposedly pre-C++11. Yes construct and destory are there and a host of other things, that as I understand it, are not required post C++11. So, where "I didn't see them" is in the C++11 reference for allocator. I am not sure if I need them or not.

Comment: 4) You use one of the container's constructors that take an allocator as a parameter. E.g. `std::vector<ComplexNumber, CustomAllocator<ComplexNumber> > myVector(CustomAllocator<ComplexNumber>(some_args));`

Comment: As I said, `construct` and `destroy` are optional, and the right thing will happen if you omit them. They used to be required mostly because, pre-C++11, it was difficult to detect whether a class provided a method with a given name, and therefore difficult to implement a fallback based on the absence of a method.

Comment: Ok, my problem now is, I do not know how to handle the member variable I want to use. When I use my custom allocator in a std::vector for example. It creates the vector, then creates a copy using that copy constructor for type U, allocates 16 bytes, calls a destructor on the original where I should be freeing my member variable,  it then calls the destuctor again where I'd be deleting twice.  A memory manager to me is not something that would be copied. There should be only one.

Comment: *"A memory manager to me is not something that would be copied. There should be only one"* Then, I suppose, make it a singleton and share it between all allocator instances.

Comment: Btw.: What problem are you **actually** trying to solve? I mean, writing an allocator is nothing that should be done without good, strong cause...

Comment: @cmaster The problem of being able to talk about custom memory management and pooling at interviews and know what I am talking about. At the time i wrote this, i was working through examples of pre-allocating pools. In this example, assume we are going to have millions of the ComplexNumber objects and we want to preallocate a pool for them, and then have them end up in that pool when we make a vector of them.

Comment: Ah. Now, that's a very valid reason for asking about custom allocators :-)